# python structlog - can i change log level dynamically but only for specific classes?

Tags: python, logging, structlog

my scenario is this - im using a simple logger, and have alot of `log.info()/log.debug()` messages in my code.

i would like to change the log level dynamically, mainly being able to "turn on/off" debug level logs.

my question is this - is it somehow possible to do so, but make the change only affect parts of my code? lets say only when im inside methods of a specific class.
or is the only way to do something like that is to use a different log object for that class and change only its level?

Comment: Are you using structlog using its stdlib integration? Either way please share your configuration.  It definitely is _possible_, but it depends on your config how.

Comment: yup, using the BoundLogger class.
structlog version 20.1.0

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this by using the stdlib logging output for structlog, and then just configure `logging` to different levels for each logger.

Every logger has a name, that is used to differenciate where the logs came from and how to handle them. usually you define a single logger per python file like this:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

What this does is give the logger the name of the python module. for example if the file is `proj/routers/route1.py` then the logger name will be `proj.routers.route1`.
This is useful because the std logging library allows you to configure a log level to the `proj.routers` logger, that will be applied to every `proj.routers.*` loggers.

see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging